# SQL re-assigning the rank based on some logic

Tags: sql, db2

Below is the sample table: `flg` 'E' means existing and 'N' means "new".

```
LOC_RANK    b       c       d       rownum  flg
---------   ------  ------  ------  ------  ---
1           (null)  (null)  (null)  1       E
1           a       b       c       2       N
2           a       b       c       3       E
2           (null)  (null)  (null)  4       N
3           (null)  (null)  (null)  5       E
3           (null)  (null)  (null)  6       N
4           a       b       c       7       E
4           a1      b1      c1      8       N
5           a       a       c       9       E 
5           a       a       c       10      N
```

Sample data :

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/226bc/5

**Requirement:**

**case 1:** So for rank `1` in table if `flg` value **E** is having null for a,c,d
column and for rank `1` in table if `flg` value **N** and having not null value then loc_rank should be same.

**case 2:** So for rank `2` in table if `flg` value **E** is having not null for a,c,d
column and for rank `2` in table if `flg` value **N** and having null value then loc_rank should be change to next incremented value.

**case 3:** So for rank `3` in table if `flg` value **E** is having null for a,c,d
column and for rank `3` in table if `flg` value **N** and having null value then loc_rank should be same.

**case 4:** So for rank `4` in table if `flg` value **E** is having not null for a,c,d
column and for rank `4` in table if `flg` value **N** and having not null value but if a,b,c same in both case then loc_rank should be same otherwise next incremented value.

I want to rearrange the output like

```
LOC_RANK    b       c       d       rownum  flg
---------   ------  ------  ------  ------  ---
1           (null)  (null)  (null)  1       E
1           a       b       c       2       N
2           a       b       c       3       E
3           (null)  (null)  (null)  4       N
4           (null)  (null)  (null)  5       E
4           (null)  (null)  (null)  6       N
5           a       b       c       7       E
6           a1      b1      c1      8       N
7           a       a       c       9       E 
7           a       a       c       10      N
```

Comment: .....I think I'm more curious about why you seem to be caring about all-null rows.  You aren't considering any other attribute data?  Then they should probably be discarded.

Comment: I need my output as it is its my business requirement @Clockwork-Muse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for your problem:

```
;with cte
AS
(
SELECT
T1.LOC_RANK AS LOC_RANK1,
T1.b AS b1,
T1.c AS c1,
T1.d AS d1,
T1.rownum AS rownum1,
T1.flg AS flg1,
T2.LOC_RANK AS LOC_RANK2,
T2.b AS b2,
T2.c AS c2,
T2.d AS d2,
T2.rownum AS rownum2,
T2.flg AS flg2,  
CASE WHEN (T1.b IS NOT NULL AND T1.c IS NOT NULL AND T1.d IS NOT NULL)
      AND ( 
                (T2.b IS NULL AND T2.c IS NULL AND T2.d IS NULL)
                 OR
                 (T2.b IS NOT NULL AND T2.c IS NOT NULL AND T2.d IS NOT NULL
                  AND T1.b <> T2.b AND T1.c <> T2.c AND T1.d <> T2.d)
           )
     THEN 1
     ELSE 0
END AS Change     
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE1 T2
ON T1.LOC_RANK = T2.LOC_RANK
AND T1.flg <> T2.flg AND T1.flg <> 'N'
)
, cte2 
AS
(
SELECT 
LOC_RANK1,
b1,
c1,
d1,
rownum1,
flg1,
LOC_RANK2,
b2,
c2,
d2,
rownum2,
flg2,  
Change,
sum(Change) OVER(ORDER BY rownum2) AS cum_change
FROM cte
)
, finalcte
AS
(
SELECT
CASE WHEN LOC_RANK1 <> 1
      THEN LOC_RANK1 + lag(cum_change) OVER (ORDER BY rownum1)
      ELSE LOC_RANK1
END AS LOC_Rank,      
b1 AS b,
c1 AS c,
d1 AS d,
rownum1 AS rownum,
flg1 AS flg
FROM 
cte2
UNION ALL
SELECT
CASE WHEN LOC_RANK2 = 1 
      THEN 
      CASE WHEN CHANGE = 1
            THEN LOC_RANK2 + CHANGE
            ELSE LOC_RANK2
      END      
      ELSE
        LOC_RANK2 + cum_change
END AS LOC_RANK,        
b2,
c2,
d2,
rownum2,
flg2
FROM 
cte2
)
SELECT *
FROM finalcte
ORDER BY LOC_Rank, flg
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
LOC_Rank       b       c       d      rownum    flg
    1        (null)  (null)  (null)    1         E
    1          a       b       c       2         N
    2          a       b       c       3         E
    3        (null)  (null)  (null)    4         N
    4        (null)  (null)  (null)    5         E
    4        (null)  (null)  (null)    6         N
    5          a       b       c       7         E
    6          a1      b1      c1      8         N
    7          a       a       c       9         E
    7          a       a       c       10        N
```

**DEMO LINK**:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f750b/32